# Configure PHP Server in PHPStorm with Vagrant on Windows 7

Tags: xdebug, vagrant, phpstorm

On my local dev machine, I have a Vagrant box with this IP 172.22.22.22. On the box I have installed PHP and Xdebug.

```
php --version

PHP 5.4.24-1~dotdeb.0 (cli) (built: Jan 12 2014 19:26:20) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

I used the following config for Xdebug:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/xdebug.so" 
xdebug.remote_enable = 1 
xdebug.remote_port = 9000 
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
```

But when I configure File --> Settings --> PHP --> Server and put in the values for everything.

I check "Use path mappings ..." and add an "Absolute path on the server" for my project "File/Directory".

When I click "Validate remote environment" I choose the deployment server and leave local path for the validation script for the local path to the project. Then I click "Validate". However, I get the error message "Please, configure path mapping for the validation directory".

But I thought that was what I did in the step above, when I checked the "Use path mappings". But do I misunderstand what the validation directory and validation script is?

Comment: *"However, I get the error message "Please, configure path mapping for the validation directory". "* -- it should be your deployment settings (most likely). Make sure that "Mappings" tab there has all fields filled and warning/errors shown.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran in to the same issue.

Project Settings -> PHP -> Servers. Add your server here. I called mine Test. In my hosts file I've called it test.vagrant, so the host is also called that (not sure if that's right).

Next, I had to add on path mappings, which is the error we were both having. This is not the best way, but it worked.

1. Click validate remote environment
2. Add your local server. I created a new server, of type "In Place"
3. Set up your mappings. In my test project, I have two folders, vagrant and www. Under www I have test. So I mapped the local folder test to an absolute web path of / .
4. Click ok, and get back to the PHP Servers screen.
5. Click the checkbox, Use path mappings
6. Map the local folder to the remote absolute path, in my case it is /var/www/test

And that should remove the error message.

Actually getting xdebug to work is something I haven't managed to do yet. So this information may not help with that, but it will definitely remove the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Just create one more directory "validation" on your local computer and create additional mapping in Deployment->Mappings. Example of my Deployment->Mappings settings:

```
Local Path        |   Deployment path     | Web path
------------------|-----------------------|-------------
c:\src\validation |   /var/www/validation |  /validation
```

After this validation should start.